# Django Authentication issue after reseting password

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.8 for my project and I have tried using `django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` in middleware to log off the other session after resetting the password. This is fine but the problem I am facing is after resetting it is logging off even that session who changed the password. I want that after resetting the password, the session where we change the password do not get log off. Our `user` model is inherited from `AbstractUser`

Comment: How are you resetting the password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use your own view to change password, django gives you ability to update the session after changing password so that the user isn't logged off.

For that you can use `update_session_auth_hash` function.

Django's `user_change_password` update the session after password change. But for you own custom views, you can use `update_session_auth_hash` like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash

def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
    else:
        ...
```

Django docs about [session invalidation on password change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change)

Instead of going through all this, you can use [`django-allauth`](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) instead. It is an awesome app and has all sort of authentication functionality to it.

Comment: @v1k34 what is form.user, can I pass request.user instead or some string, because I have a custom form, which only contains password field.

Comment: Yes, you can pass `request.user` too. The above code just makes sure to update session auth has of the user we supplied to change password.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the accepted answer didn't work for me. So I did the obvious... I logged in the user again as usual. Example of a ChangePasswordForm overriding the save() method.

```py
class ChangePasswordForm(models.Form):
    old_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        # authenticate user here (using old_password)
        # check if password1 == password2
        return data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
            login(self.request, user) # HERE IS THE WHOLE THING        

        return user
```